# Get an array, decide if the number is closer to right/left zero

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a code which gets an integer array, check every index's value, if the index's value is zero it goes on until it finds an index with value which isn't zero and then changes its value depending on the closer zero in the array. for example:

```
  BEFORE  ( 0, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0) 

  AFTER ( 0, 1 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 0)
```

This is my code:

```
       public static void zeroDistance (int [] a)
   {
       int counterToZero = 0;
       int counterToZeroII = 0;
       for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ){
                counterToZero = 0;
                counterToZeroII = -1;
                if ( a[i] != 0 ){
                  for ( int j = i; a[j] != 0; j++)
                  { // From i to the next zero
                          counterToZero++;
                  }
                  for ( int h = i; a[h] != 0 ; h--) // From i to first zero (goes beckwards)
                  {
                        counterToZeroII++;
                  }
                  if ( counterToZero > counterToZeroII ) 
                  a[i] = counterToZero;
                  else if (counterToZero < counterToZeroII)
                  a[i] = counterToZeroII;
                  else if ( counterToZero == counterToZeroII)
                  a[i] = counterToZero;
                }
       }
       int[] b = a;
       for (int h = 0; h < b.length; h++)
        System.out.println(b[h] + "/n");
   }
```

This is the output I'm getting, and I'm kinda lost of where the problem is, I'm still looking on the code and trying to detect what I did wrong, if you can help me out and point where I may be wrong it'd be very helpful. also, if u know another way of "sort checking" like using recursion it'd be much appreciated, I'm trying to get used to using recursion but it's still hard for me to implement that thus I'm using for loops at the moment.

0/n
2/n
1/n
0/n
5/n
4/n
3/n
3/n
4/n
0/n

Comment: @Illan Aizelman WS If I'm not wrong the 4th value in 'AFTER' sequence should be 3 instead of 2. Isn't it?

Comment: @Razib no, because there is a zero at the 6th positon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can propose you a simple way to do it. You first go from left to right and consider only the closest left zero. Then you go from right to left and consider only the closest right zero. Replace the previous distance with the new one if it is smaller.

Here is how it is implemented :

```
public static void zeroDistance (int [] a) {
    // closest == -1 means no zero was found yet
    int closest = -1;
    for (int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++) 
       if (a[i] == 0) 
           closest = 0;
       else {         
           // short version
           // a[i] = closest == -1 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : ++closest;

           // simpler version for your to understand
           if (closest == -1) 
               a[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
           else {
               closest++;
               a[i] = closest;
           }                    
       }
    closest = -1;
    for (int i=a.length-1 ; i>=0 ; i--) 
       if (a[i] == 0)                            
           closest = 0;
       else if (closest != -1 && a[i] > ++closest) 
           a[i] = closest;       
}
```

Ouput for your example :

```
0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0
```

Comment: I wrote an implementation, haven't tested yet

Comment: What did you do here? a[i] = closer == -1 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : ++closer; Can you make it simpler and not in one line, i find hard to understand it. @Dici

Comment: Thanks! What Integer.MAX_VALUE is for? I don't see any reason to write it o.o

Comment: And I can't seem to understand, how it really checks all the zero's until the given value (from the left side), because it always increments the i value.

Comment: At first, you can have any value in your array, let's say you have a `[ 1,5,5,0 ]`. You see that the first element has no left zero, and a right zero at a distance of 3. Let's imagine I don't set it to Integer.MAX_VALUE during the left to right iteration, then when I will iterate from right to left and reach index 0, my variable `closest` will be 3. `3 > 1` so the first element would stay 1 instead of 3.

Comment: When I meet a zero, I reset my counter `closest` so that we know the distance of the left closest zero

Comment: It performs exactly `2n` operations, so it is a `O(n)`

Comment: and what about this?  a[i] > ++closest , I don't understand why you check here the value of the index. how will it help you determine that it is closer to the right zero?

Comment: The current value `a[i]` represents the distance of the closest left zero, while `closest + 1` is (in this part of the code) the closest right zero. I update the `a[i]` only if the distance of the closest right zero is lower than the distance of the closest left zero

Comment: Couldn't manage to understand the code, dam it. I'll try to get help from someone help I don't want to waste your time. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68149/discussion-between-dici-and-ilan-aizelman-ws).

Comment: Haha no problem, if you want we can do it on the chat and step through the code

Comment: today after I cleaned my head, I understood your code within less than 10minutes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using recursion

```
public static void zeroDistance(int a[]){
    for(int x=0;x<a.length;x++){
        if(a[x]!=0){
            int leftdist=recurse(-1,a,0,x);
            int rightdist=recurse(1,a,0,x);
            int bestdist;
            if(leftdist<0||rightdist<0)
                bestdist=Math.max(leftdist,rightdist);//one (or (hopefully not) both of them) is negative(nothing awaits thou)
            else
                bestdist=Math.min(leftdist,rightdist);//both are positive, get the better one
            a[x]=bestdist;
        }
    }
}
public static int recurse(int dir,int a[],int count,int index){
    if(a[index]==0)//if we found a zero give back the count
        return count;
    if(index==0||index==a.length-1)//if we reached the end without getting a zero give negative one
        return -1;
    return recurse(dir,a,count+1,index+dir);//keep going

}
```